# Missing codec on listing with DirectShow

Tags: vb.net, video, directshow, video-codecs

We have a desktop Windows (32bit only) app which shows a list of the codecs installed in the computer.

However, we are finding that sometimes this list does not get every codec installed, as we have found cases - without any particularity - where we install *h264vfw* codecs and the installation is made successfully. After that, however, the list does not show the codec on the list.

Here is the code we use to get the full codecs list:

```
Dim DsDevice as DirectShowLib.DsDevice

Private Function LlistaVideoCodecs() As List(Of String)        
    LlistaVideoCodecs = New List(Of String)        
    Dim llista = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoCompressorCategory)
       For Each oDevice As DsDevice In llista            
           If oDevice IsNot Nothing Then 
               LlistaVideoCodecs.Add(oDevice.Name)        
       Next        
    Return LlistaVideoCodecs    
End Function
```

How could we get the full codec list of all the codec installed? Why *h264vfw* codec is not showing even when installing it successfully?

Thank you for your time and your help.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet is about right. DirectShow itself (its Intelligent Connect) looks for codecs similar way.

The typical problem is that there are two separate independent lists: 32-bit codecs and 64-bit codecs. When you install 32-bit codec, the 64-bit list does not have it, and vice versa.

When you enumerate codecs, you are walking through the list which matches the bitness of your code. "Installed but invisible" codec is in your case in the other list, and of a different bitness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though our app works only in 32-bit mode, we will check that possibility! As soon as we can I will update/answer if this was the cause! Thank you again.